# How do i get the id of a row after i stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I just executed a stored procedure which inserts flight information to my table and I wanted to get the id after every insert that I made. But I was not able to find other ways that could work for me. I wanted to get the flight_id which is on auto_increment.

```
mysqli_query($conn,"CALL addschedule('$airlineID','$from','$to','$departDate','$arriveDate','$departTime','$arrivalTime','$price')");

$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
echo $last_id;
```

Running `mysqli_insert_id` only returns me a value of 0 but my last flight id was 3. Can anyone give me a clear explanation?

Answer (score 3):

> mysqli_insert_id — Returns the auto generated id used in the last query
>
> The mysqli_insert_id() function returns the ID generated by a query on a table with a column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. If the last query wasn't an INSERT or UPDATE statement or if the modified table does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, this function will return zero.

So please check you had set AUTO_INCREMENT attribute to your `id` field.

OR if you had set it AUTO_INCREMENT. this sample code might help you.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");


$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
$mysqli->query($query);

/* In op's case
mysqli->query($conn,"CALL addschedule('$airlineID','$from','$to','$departDate','$arriveDate','$departTime','$arrivalTime','$price')");
*/

printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);


/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

**ANSWER 2**

In your SP

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000);
select LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

In you php code

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn,"CALL addschedule('$airlineID','$from','$to','$departDate','$arriveDate','$departTime','$arrivalTime','$price')");

echo "Last ID: ".$result;
```

This might do your work.

**PS**: I didn't test this code. hope to work

Comment: it still returns me 0. does it work after stored procedures?

Comment: doesnt work with stored procedures. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759023/stored-procedures-and-mysql-insert-id-issue

Comment: Thanks but how do i manage to get the last id from stored procedures?

Comment: in your SP use `LAST_INSERT_ID();` which is mysql function. more detail you can find here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html